# How to break powershell script execution on first error?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am using a PowerShell script that completes 5 different interdependent tasks sequentially. I want the script to stop execution as soon as it hits a catch block and send an email. Also, this script executes a console app. How do I stop execution of the PowerShell script in case of a console exception? I am logging console exceptions using the `-RedirectStandardError` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Stopping execution in the catch block is accomplished by using the Break keyword, this should be added last, e.g.:

```
    Catch
{
    Send-MailMessage -From ExpensesBot@MyCompany.Com -To WinAdmin@MyCompany.Com -Subject "HR File Read Failed!" -SmtpServer EXCH01.AD.MyCompany.Com
    Break
}
```

If you want to catch non-terminating errors as well, you'll need:

```
-ErrorAction Stop
```

at the end of your commandlet (or set it as a preference / session setting)

https://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell

Comment: `-ErrorAction` is unrecognized in `Powershell version 5.1.14393.953`.. or Am I doing something wrong?: `cat script.ps1 | powershell -ErrorAction Stop -command -` (It also didn't recognize `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`)